# How can I change the size of the canvas gradient?

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas, path, 2d

I want to scale the gradient without changing its container.
For example, apply scale or rotate on the created gradient object.

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')

gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 75, 10, 75, 75, 50)

gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red')
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green')

ctx.fillStyle = gradient

//how change scaleX or scaleY or rotation from gradient object?!

//draw main container
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150)//don't change scale or size
```

Comment: Instead of `fillRect()` use `rect()`, before you transform the context. And call `fill()` after you did: https://jsfiddle.net/15y2sk08/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would go about rotating a radial gradient, but scaling it is pretty simple. Just change r0 to change the radius of the pure red circle, and change r1 to change where pure green starts. In between these two values the colors are interpolated, which makes the gradient. Hope this helps.

```js
const canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var r0 = 10;
var r1 = 50;

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 75, r0, 75, 75, r1);

gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green');

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to change the value of scaleX or scaleY, not both at the same time.